# extract image content in a string variable

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat6, ocr, tesseract

i would extract the text from an image in a string variable, so i use Tess4j to do this and it's work fine when i create a new project and test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TesseractException {  
        File image=new File("eurotext.tif");
        Tesseract instance=Tesseract.getInstance();
        String result = instance.doOCR(image);
        System.out.println(result);         
        }
```

but when i try to integrate tess4j into myproject i get exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input not set!
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.getNumImages
(TIFFImageReader.java:28)
    at net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.getIIOImageList(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
```

is there another method to extract the text without using ocr?

i dont know why i get this error but it  invoke TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text

```
    java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:470)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:404)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy7.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Tesseract.java:336)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:232)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:173)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:158)
```

is someone has already used tess4j with tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having the "Invalid memory access" because you must define the datapath of the traineddata to use. If you don't specify the language it will assume it is eng.

For instance, it your project path is PROJECT and your trained data is at PROJECT/data/tessdata/eng.traineddata

```
tess.setDatapath("data");
tess.setLanguage("eng");
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on that... so how does `tess.setDatapath("data");
tess.setLanguage("eng");` correlate to the folder structure? Shouldn't it be `tess.setDatapath("data/tessdata/eng.traineddata")` ? Btw, in my web app, I have `WEB-INF/classes/tessdata/eng.traineddata` and `WEB-INF/classes/tessdata/config/api_config,digits,hocr` so what should I be setting with `tess,setDatapath()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not set the input. Make sure you have the correct path to the image.

Comment: i set the input but now i get this error:
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Native Method)
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Tesseract.java:323)
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:220)
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:161)
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:146)

Comment: It should invoke `TessAPI.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text`. I don't know why it's different in your case.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a third reason, other than data-path and valid input image. i think it has to do with tesseract not being able to recognize image boundaries in some cases. I was able to get rid of the error by using a BufferedImage, and instead of passing a null Rectangle, passing a Rectangle( 0, 0, imageWidth-1, imageHeight -1)